# Account logs out when i change the language of the site

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, language

I'm currently using Joomla! 3.4.8 for my multi-language site, for the member access area I've created menu links of type "connexion" for each language with associations between them.
My problem here is, when i switch between the languages the user logs out and i need to log in in each time, what might be the problem here? what am i doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Joomla's built-in language feature or a 3rd party extension?

Comment: I'm using the module of type "Language Switcher"

Answer (score 1):

Please check the status that the language-switch module ist published. If the status is not public, this may cause the issue.

Comment: The access to the language switcher is public.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in URLs.

Please make sure that when language switches you stay on the same site version and not going from www to non-www and vice versa.

Cause if this is changed - you may be logged in at first version and you would be logged out at second.

Comment: Where can i change the URLs?

Comment: check livesite variable in configuration. php (I'm personally avoiding to use it) and set up htaccess redirects